# Pyspark: operation on values based on type

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I've got such an RDD:

```
[('a', ('H', 1)), ('b', (('H', 41), ('S', 1)))]
```

so that keys can have either a single `tuple` or a `tuple` of `tuples` as values. This comes from a `reduceByKey`.
I need to perform a simple operation: divide the counts of S for the counts of (H + S). 
When S is not there, like in the case of the first item, I will have to return 0. 
The problem is to isolate the first case (single `tuple`) from the second (`tuple` of two `tuples`) so that I know how to operate in a `map`.

How would I proceed?

Comment: How do you get data like this in the first place? Is it some kind of hierarchical structure with specific meaning? If not I would make more sense to enforce consistent shaper upstream. Python provides basic dispatch mechanisms since 3.4 but these are shallow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking it would make more sense to fix this upstream but you can try for example something like this:

```
from operator import truediv

def f(vs):
    try:
        d = dict(vs)
    except ValueError:
        d = dict([vs])

    s = sum(d.values())
    return truediv(d.get("S", 0), s) if s else float('nan')

rdd = sc.parallelize([('a', ('H', 1)), ('b', (('H', 41), ('S', 1)))])
rdd.mapValues(f).collect()

## [('a', 0.0), ('b', 0.023809523809523808)]
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind external dependencies, you can try to use [`multipledispatch`](https://github.com/mrocklin/multipledispatch/):

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch

@dispatch(tuple, tuple)
def f(h, s):
    try:
        return truediv(s[1], h[1] + s[1])
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return float('nan')

@dispatch(str, int)
def f(x, y):
    return 0.0

rdd.mapValues(lambda args: f(*args)).collect()
## [('a', 0.0), ('b', 0.023809523809523808)]
```

Comment: I like the dispatch approach which does exactly what it should hiding an ugliness of `isinstance`. But it requires relatively complex code. If go a happy path (don't enter `except` block the first one should faster). Exception handling is quite expensive though so I expect that amortized cost will be higher. In general I would really fix this upstream and provide input that can be consumed directly.